# JavaScript parallax transform transitions onscroll

Tags: javascript, css, transition

I am trying to set up a parallax like background. The goal here is to have certain elements transform: translate() at different scroll heights.  I've seen multiple people do it with jQuery, but i am more looking for the JavaScript approach considering I am very new with JS.

my code currently looks like this...

```
window.onscroll = function() {
  windowScroll();
};

function windowScroll() {

  var scrollInput = window.scrollY;
  console.log("scroll from top: " + scrollInput);


  var portrait = document.querySelector(".portrait");
  portrait.style.transform = "translate(0px, + 'scrollInput' /2 %)";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [parallax.js](http://matthew.wagerfield.com/parallax/)

by using this you can see more parallel effects